# enqueuing jobs using sucker punch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, job-scheduling

I have one doubt with enqueuing the job using sucker punch.

I have 2000+ search keywords in my database I want to know the google and bing ranking for each keyword in my database. For this I'm using [Authority Labs API](https://authoritylabs.com/api/). But AuthorityLabs will only process 1000 POST request in 1 hour. I'm sending each request to AuthorityLab as a background job using sucker punch. How can I limit only 1000 jobs will run in 1 hour, remaining jobs only start after one hour. Also I want to run this jobs daily for analysing the rank change.

Answer (score 0):

Rate limiting is not a concern of your queue system, much less of SuckerPunch that is not designed to handle advanced delaying/queuing stuff, it just moves asynchronous jobs to a thread from a thread pool.

If you really want to have rate limiting, use a real queue system like Sidekiq, and put some actual code to work.

Sidekiq Enterprise supports it natively: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Rate-Limiting
Sidekiq-throttler seems to provide the same functionality: https://github.com/gevans/sidekiq-throttler

But you can also just delay execution (so pre-emptively limiting the rate), by enqueuing jobs at specific times in the future (each executing 4 minutes after the other) or enqueuing just one job that executes itself (doing next outstanding request) and enqueues itself again with 4 minutes delay.

As always with open source, check the code and decide by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
YourProcessingJob.set(wait: 1.hours).perform_later
```

Possibly in a custom rake task...